# Express session is undefined when accessing from different route?

Tags: node.js, session, express, session-variables, express-session

Im trying to implement infinite scroll. In my first route I load 5 elements from the data base and store the id of the last seen item. To load more data getNextHomeContent is called, but for some reason req.session.lastseen is undefined.

**server.js**

```
var express  = require('express');
var session = require('express-session');
var app      = express();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var logger = require('morgan');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cors = require('cors');

//imports database configuration
var databaseConfig = require('./config/database');

//defines route file to use
var router = require('./app/routes');

//connect to datbase
mongoose.connect(databaseConfig.url);

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
console.log("App listening on port 8080");


app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })); // Parses urlencoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // Send JSON responses
app.use(logger('dev')); // Log requests to API using morgan
app.use(cors());

app.use(session({
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 60000,
    secure: false
  }
}));
router(app);
```

And here is my controller for my routes in **homeCtrl.js**

```
exports.getHomeContent = function(req, res, next) {
    req.session.lastseen = null;
    homeContent.find({})
        .sort({
            "_id": -1
        })
        .limit(5)
        .exec(function(err, content) {
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
            }
            var last = content.slice(-1);
            req.session.lastseen = last[0]._id;
            console.log("lastseen first is " + req.session.lastseen);
            res.json(content);
        });
}

exports.getNextHomeContent = function(req, res, next) {
    console.log("lastseen is " + req.session.lastseen);

    homeContent.find({
            "_id": { "$lt": req.session.lastseen }
        })
        .sort({
            "_id": -1
        })
        .limit(5)
        .exec(function(err, content) {
            if (err) { res.send(err); }
            console.log("WTF:" + content.slice(-1));
            var lastitem = content.slice(-1);
            req.session.lastseen = lastitem[0]._id;
            res.json(content);
        });
}
```

When get Home content runs, req.session.lastname is set to the ID of the last item. However req.session.lastitem becomes undefined when getNextHomeContent() runs. Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks!!

Comment: Every time I've used express-session without any other backing store, I've found that I need to call `req.session.save()` for any request where I changed something in the session object if I wanted the change to persist.  It does not seem like this should be required if `resave: true` is configured, but that has been my experience.  I'd suggest adding `req.session.save()` after you set `req.session.lastseen`.

Comment: FYI, storing the infinity state scroll in the session will not work properly if the user ever has two separate windows open at once because there's only one value for `.lastseen` in the session but there can be multiple windows open each with their own state.  That problem can be solved by keeping the state for what the client needs next in the client itself (either as query parameters or just JS variables in the page) so each window has its own separate state.

Comment: Thanks for your insight, however I have tried using req.session.save() and this seems to have no effect. Also, the application is a mobile app so there will only ever be one page open therefore using one instance of .lastseen should be sufficient...